# Change the name and extension of a static file served with node

Tags: node.js

So I have some static files stored in a `uploads` folder running in my node.js application, but their name and extension (all of them are PDFs) were replaced by a mysql `CHAR(32)` string reference in DB.

I need to serve them with a comprehensible name (autogenerated in server) and it's original extension back. Any hints?

Comment: I don't know which db you are using but you could also store the extension as a field or property of the file stored...

Comment: No worries about that. All of the files are, for sure, PDFs. I just need to replace dynamically the name and the extension, so when a user asks for `<server-url>/uploads/729a2fc4a1203cf8bf0c1d97bae82576` they download `Example.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with HTTP headers.

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Example.pdf
Content-type: application/pdf
```